# What's wrong with the most cited binary tree depth calculation algorithm?

Tags: binary-tree, computer-science

There is something that eats into my brain: how can the depth of the following tree

```
  b
 / \
a   c
```

be `3`, after the most cited algorithm (here in Java):

```
int depth(Node n)
{
    if(n == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int lDepth = depth(n.left);
    int rDepth = depth(n.right);

    return 1 + ((lDepth > rDepth) ? lDepth : rDepth);
}
```

when the depth of a tree with only a single (root) node is `0` according to Wikipedia and many of my other sources where the depth is defined as length of path to the deepest node? Obviously, the length of the path to the deepest node for a tree with only a single node is `0`, while the above algorithm will never yield anything smaller than `1`.

Is the depth of a tree with a single root node `0` or is it `1`? If it is `0` then the algorithm above is faulty, because it will yield `1`.

I never thought such a trivial thing would turn inside out on me.

Comment: It is whatever you want it to be, as long as you are consistent. As defined in this algorithm, it's 1.

Answer (score 0):

The height of a tree is usually defined as:

`1. The number of edges on the longest path from the root to a leaf`

or

`2. The number of nodes on the longest path from the root to a leaf`

Of course you can easily transform a result given by any of the above definitions to a result of the other - just subtract/add 1.

You are correct, that the first definition is used more frequently.

As you can see, the algorithm which you are according to, follows the second definition.